# Force close an opened (but hidden...) TCP port on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, process, port

I have a really weird and annoying issue. I develop an application which opens a lot of TCP ports (using WCF, if that matters at all). Sometimes, I can start my application because a port remains open. When I check for that port using netstat, I can find its process id:

```
C:\Users\baprins>netstat -ano | find "8249"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8249           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       22640
  TCP    [::]:8249              [::]:0                 LISTENING       22640
  TCP    [::1]:8249             [::1]:59541            ESTABLISHED     22640
  TCP    [::1]:8249             [::1]:59543            ESTABLISHED     22640
  TCP    [::1]:59541            [::1]:8249             ESTABLISHED     22640
  TCP    [::1]:59543            [::1]:8249             ESTABLISHED     22640
```

When I open process explorer to find that process, it's not listed!

[image]

Is there another way to force close this port? Is there another way to find these "zombied" processes?

The only alternative I have now, is rebooting, which in my case is really cumbersome...

Comment: Is the offending process always the Discovery Service?

Comment: Clean up properly when your application exits and close the ports.

Comment: Have you run process explorer as Admin?